# Equivalence relation in singular homology

Tags: algebraic-topology

I'm currently reading Rotman's Introduction to algebraic topology, and I'm struggling to understand what singular homology is.

The definition of a singular simplex isn't clear to me. If a singular simplex is any continuous map from the standard n simplex, then there are uncountably many of them (except for some special spaces). The point that I don't get is how all of those simplexes "cancel" each other in the homology group. I read about an equivalence relation that takes care of it but I didn't understand.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you know about simplicial homology? Has Rotman talked about that yet? How do simplexes "cancel" there?

Comment: @Arthur Yes, I read the chapter about simplicial homology. Are you talking about the end of the chapter where he discusses adequate subcomplexes?

Comment: I haven't read the book, so I don't know. But singular homology is just like simplicial homology, only there are a few more simplexes. Consider how the size of the simplicial complex doesn't affect the size of the homology at all. (You can use two $2$-simplexes to cover a torus, or thousands, the homology is the same.) Why? Basically the same thing happens in singular homology. Yes, there are uncountably many simplexes, but you only ever work with finitely many of them at a time.

Comment: @Arthur I'm not sure I understood you. Do you mean that for almost every simplex there is another simplex so that their boundaries cancel in the homology group?

Comment: @Arthur Even if I can cover the torus with infinite triangles or just two, when it comes to singular homology there is another thing that bothers me. If the maps are singular, then the simplexes "cross" each other, which means that there isn't a single partition of the space but infinitely many.

Answer (score 0):

You are sort of correct. Singular homology is not really "computable".

However, one can show that it is naturally isomorphic to (semi)simplicial homology, CW homology, etc, and others are somewhat computable, giving you the results.

Simplexes do not trivially cancel as what you expected.